# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}?$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am confused about the notation used in partial derivatives. Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}?$

I assume that Young's theorem may not hold, and hence, the values may not be equal under symmetry.

Comment: The ordering of the letters is reversed between the two notations. The derivative in question is $f_{yx}$

Comment: $f_{yx}=\left( f_y \right)_x$, so differentiating wrt $y$ first, then differentiating wrt $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial derivatives are just functions of a sort, so you work inside outward:

$$\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\pdv{}{x} \left( \pdv{f}{y} \right) = \pdv{}{x} \left( f_y \right) = (f_y)_x$$

From here, we simply adopt the shorthand $f_{yx} = (f_y)_x$.

---

In short, your second notation is the correct one. When you have subscripts, the order of differentiation is left to right: $f_{xyz}$ is $f$ differentiated w.r.t. $x$, then $y$, then $z$.

When using the differential notation, the order is right to left, or rather inside-out, because these are operators.